# How to copy echo 'x' to file during an ssh connection

Tags: shell, ssh, echo

I have a script which starts an ssh-connection.
so the variable `$ssh` start the ssh connection.

so `$SSH` hostname gives the hostname of the host where I ssh to.
Now I try to echo something and copy the output of the echo to a file.

SSH="ssh -tt -i key.pem user@ec2-instance"

When I perform a manual ssh to the host and perform:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DEVS=/dev/xvdbb' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup"
```

it works.
But when I perform

```
${SSH} sudo sh -c "echo 'DEVS=/dev/xvdb' > /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup"
```

it does not seem to work.

EDIT:
Also using tee is working fine after performing an ssh manually but does not seem to work after the ssh in the script.sh

The echo command after an ssh of the script is happening on my real host (from where I'm running the script, not the host where I'm performing an ssh to). So the file on my real host is being changed and not the file on my host where I've performed an ssh to.

Comment: When I try the right answer of over here: http://superuser.com/questions/400714/how-to-remotely-write-to-a-file-using-ssh I got a permission denied. (even if I perform sudo)

Comment: If you leave the `>` unquoted you would change the local system file. As written that shouldn't happen. Show the "permission error" you are getting and the command you are running. Also show the local file before and after. Also run `set -x` and then run the command (using `sh -cx`) and show the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command passed to `ssh` will be executed by the remote shell, so you need to add one level of quoting:

```
${SSH} "sudo sh -c \"echo 'DEVS=/dev/xvdb' > /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup\""
```

The only thing you really need on the server is the writing though, so if you don't have password prompts and such you can get rid of some of this nesting:

```
echo 'DEVS=/dev/xvdb' | $SSH 'sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup'
```

Comment: Thanks! The first command works fine. The second one show me 2 times the DEVS=/dev/xvdb and than it gets stuck (don't know why, the shell script doesn't go further. But the first command works fine!